# Max-Flow Min-Cut

Tags: algorithm, graph

Assuming there is a flow network G=(V,E) with c : E->R+ as a capacity function,
we can find the min-cut (A,B).
What would happen if we delete the cut's edges, i.e - the forwarded edges from A to B?
I'd be grateful if anyone could point me to the answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "what would happen?"

Comment: in terms of max flow mainly .. i'd also like to know if it will affect the graph connectivity

Answer (score 1):

You will find that you have deleted a minimum cut and that there are no edges with positive capacity from A to B --- in particular, if you pick a vertex a in A and a vertex b in B, there is no path from a to b with positive capacity on each edge.

Comment: but the min-cut is not unique and there might be another min-cut which contains another edges...

Comment: @Itamar: So?  You can't push any more flow across this cut.

Comment: first of all , thanks for the answers so far ! i'm mainly interested to know what would happen to the max flow, i'd be grateful if you could tell me about it

Comment: @Itamar: as tmyklebu stated, the max flow between any vertex a in A and any other vertex b in B would drop to 0 since there would be no more path leading from A to B. The fact that the min cut isn't unique doesn't influence that since all min cuts will disconnect A from B (because all of them are cuts). The fact that they are min cuts just mean that the sum of the cost of the edges that are removed is minimal among all A-B cuts.